# Error setting Twitter external sign-in with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twitter, asp.net-authentication

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.2 application and the twitter authorization has started showing an `Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)` error. I have triple checked the ClientId, ClientSecret and also the Website url, callback url, Terms and conditions url, Privacy policy url and everything seems to be ok(Please see screenshot below).
Any inputs on what my next steps should be?

The documentation at [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html) says `"The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits . Other reasons for this status being returned are listed alongside the error codes in the table below."`.

How can I trap the error code(along with the HTTP status code(403 in this case)) when ASP.Net Core twitter authentication communicates with Twitter?

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
 #region Add Twitter Authentication
        .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
        {
          twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["TwitterAuthSettings:ClientId"];
          twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["TwitterAuthSettings:ClientSecret"];
          twitterOptions.SaveTokens = true;
          twitterOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = oAuthCreatingTicketContext =>
           {
             var authenticationTokens = oAuthCreatingTicketContext.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();
             var authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken()
             {
               Name = "TicketCreated",
               Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
             };
             authenticationTokens.Add(authenticationToken);
             oAuthCreatingTicketContext.Properties.StoreTokens(authenticationTokens);
             return Task.CompletedTask;
           };
          twitterOptions.Events.OnTicketReceived = ticketReceivedContext =>
           {
             return Task.CompletedTask;
           };
          twitterOptions.Events.OnRemoteFailure = remoteFailureContext =>
           {
             return Task.CompletedTask;
           };
        })
      #endregion Add Twitter Authentication
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Exception occured: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).    
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at Scrubber.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) in /src/Scrubber/ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 25
```

[image]